# Onclick visible div box

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu, onclick

I want to make the mobile navigation visible after clicking on the menu button. Here is the [example](http://www.c-kork.com). You need to make the browser smaller to see it.

I have this for the mobile navigation button

```
<div id="nav-trigger">
<span>Menu</span>
</div>
```

And when i click on it it should make the #nav-mobile div visible

```
<nav id="nav-mobile">
<ul>
    <li class="akt">Teams</li>
    <a href="partners.htm"><li>Partners</li></a>
    <a href="contact.htm"><li>Contact</li></a>
    <a href="guides.htm"><li>Guides</li></a>
    <a href="streams.htm"><li>Streams</li></a>
    <a href="shop.htm"><li>Shop</li></a>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

I was looking for a good javascript solution but my javascript is still not good enough to handle it. But when i look at the code i can understand it.

In the css i use display: none and display: block to make the navigations visible and not visible for specific screen sizes. So it would be easy to have a javascript that makes the display: block enable on a diffrent div box.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML was messed up so I corrected it. You just need to toggle the visibility state of the menu. This is not the ideal approach as far as accessibility is concerned but you should be able to get started and make improvements as needed.

```js
(function(trigger, menu) {
  /** toggle menu class name on click */
  function fn(event) {
    if (event.target.id === trigger.id || event.target.parentElement.id === trigger.id) {
      menu.classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('click', fn, false);
}(document.querySelector('#nav-trigger'), document.querySelector('#nav-mobile')));
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Onclick visible div box</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="nav-trigger">
    <span>Menu</span>
  </div>

  <nav id="nav-mobile" class="hidden">
    <ul>
      <li class="akt">Teams</li>
      <li><a href="partners.htm">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="guides.htm">Guides</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="streams.htm">Streams</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="shop.htm">Shop</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```